# Java - Find the class name and the methods in that class also find the arguments available for the method

Tags: java, dynamic-data, dynamic-programming

I have a package where i have to find all the class available in the package and methods available for the particular class and arguments for the methods available in the method.

like :

```
package com.test.dynamic;

public class Test{
Public testMethod(int test, String strArgument){
//some implementation
}
}
```

in this if i give package name than i must be able to get class name : `Test` and method name `testMethod` and arguments `test and strArgument` if possible their `types` also.

how to do this in java.

Best Regards

Comment: What did you try ? Look up reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through Reflection API in java there are many methods like getName(), getInstance()..etc it will help you: http://www.roseindia.net/java/reflect/Class.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Reflection will do every thing for you
see this link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html

Answer (score 1):

offcourse..You should read reflection tutorials.Below code can give you some pointers.**Reflection is getting the information of classes at runtime.**

```
Method[] methods = IsAccountIdAvailable.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Method Name-"+methods[i].getName());
      System.out.println("Method Parameters-"+methods[i].getGenericParameterTypes());
      System.out.println("Method Return Type-"+methods[i].getGenericReturnType());
    }
```